# Swagger - nested $ref not working

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am not able to nest $ref files in Swagger 2.0.

I am trying to define my API where-in I have provided the first `$ref` statement:

```
definitions:
  collection-response:
    type: "object"
    properties: 
      response-status: 
        $ref: './schema/response-status.schema'
```

The `response-status.schema` is a separate file in the schema folder. 
**response-status.schema** is defined as below:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "http-code": {
      "type": "integer",
      "description": "HTTP-Code being returned",
    },
    "error-block": {
      "$ref": "error-block.schema"
    }
  }
}
```

Now Swagger-UI is not able to take the second nested $ref, which in this case is the file *error-block.schema*

Please help. Is this a wrong way of doing things? 
What do I do in case I have such nested references?

Comment: My guess is that Swagger-UI simply doesn't support that. I suggest you create a feature request.